# How to repeat code when exception happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to connect two PCs, but when one of the PCs is not on I get an exception that the connection was refused, because the other PC isn't on, so I thought that when this exception happens I just re-execute this part until it succeeds, so when the other PC turns on.

This is what I have:

```
def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    host = "Alex-PC"
    port = 8080
    s.connect((host,port))

    if traceback.format_exception(ConnectionRefusedError):
        main()
```

I thought that an `if` statement might work, but I have no idea how to write the `if` statement for this problem.

Comment: Did you read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) already?

Comment: Your mistake was to focus on the word "traceback". A traceback is the information that is attached to an exception that is telling you where the error happened. What you were looking for is "exception handling".

Comment: You also might need to be careful here as calling `main()` recursively will reach a default threshold surprisingly quickly.

Comment: You should also read [this earlier part of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) which teaches you how to repeat stuff.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response for more complete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to handle an exception (such `ConnectionRefusedError`), you should use a [Try/Except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause.

This will try to execute the code inside the `try` and, if it fails, it will execute the `except` clause (if the raised `Exception` matches with the declared on the `except`)

**EDIT** with the suggestions from comments:

In your specific case, you can do something like the following:

```
import threading
import socket
t = 1

def connect(s, host, port):
    try:
        s.connect((host,port))
    except:
        print(f"Host {host} is not available. Retrying in {t} seconds...")
        time.sleep(t)
        t*=2
        connect(s, host, port)
        
def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    host = "Alex-PC"
    port = 8080
    connect(s, host, port)
```

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to recursively call `connect()` like this as python has a default depth of only 1000. So if one is waiting for a second PC to be powered on, this will reach the recursion depth in the blink of an eye.

Comment: This will raise a `NameError`, since `port` is undefined. Also, the except-block will raise a `TypeError`, since `connect` is called without the required arguments.

Comment: You are right. Edited. I just wanted to show them the try/except clause and I didn't put care on details

Comment: @Latra You still haven't fixed all the errors. Both the `connect` calls have missing arguments, and `time.sleep` will rasie an `NameError`. But calling `connect` recursively like that is still a *very bad idea*. Just use a for-loop in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method when calling you function:

```
temp = 1

def main():
    s = socket.socket()
    host = "Alex-PC"
    port = 8080
    s.connect((host,port))
    temp = 0

while(1):
    if temp == 1:
        try:
            main()
        except:
            temp = 1
    elif temp == 0: break
```

Comment: @JonSG Actually, it creates an infinite loop, because `temp` is global, so it never gets set to zero, and the while-loop never breaks.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh ya, right.. It is more convoluted than I though :-)